# Central limit theorem in [R]

Tags: r, statistics, probability, normal-distribution, probability-theory

I am working with the language [R] to generate a sample of M = 32000 averages each calculated by averaging 36 independent values ​​of the random variable continuous uniform distribution (0, 1) is generated as follows:

```
sampleA<-1:32000

for ( i in 1:32000){
    MuestraAUnif<- runif(36)
    sampleA[i]<-mean(MuestraAUnif)
}
```

For the sample generated ask me calculate relative frequency of observed averages greater than L = 0.32 +4 * 1 / 100 and compare it with the probability (approximated by "[Central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)") that the average N values ​​greater than L. as follows:

```
    L<- 0.32+4*1/100
    sigma<- sqrt(1/12) #(b-a)/12 
    miu = 0.5 #(a+b)/2
    greaterA <-sum(sampleA > L) #values of the sample greater than L are 23693
    xBar<- greaterA/length(sampleA) 
    X <- sum(sampleA) 
    n<-32000
    Zn<- (X - n*miu)/(sigma*sqrt(n))

    cat("P(xBar >",L,") = P(Z>", Zn, ")=","1 - P (Z < ", Zn,") =",1-pnorm(Zn),"\n") #print the theoretical prob Xbar greater than L
    cat("sum (sampleA >",L,")/","M=", n," para N =", 36,":",xBar, "\n") #print the sampling probability print when is greater than L
```

The output is:

```
P(xBar > 0.36 ) = P(Z> -3.961838 )= 1 - P (Z <  -3.961838 ) = 0.9999628 
sum (sampleA > 0.36 )/ M= 32000  para N = 36 : 0.7377187
```

My question is: Why are so far values​​?, Presumably they should be much closer (0.9999628 is far from 0.7377187). Am I doing something wrong with my implementation?. Excuse my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Melkhiah66. You did everything right only change 
`MuestraAUnif<- runif(2)` for `MuestraAUnif<- runif(32)`
and it should work

Comment: I already did, was my mistake to copy, but still does not work or does not tell me the result I want

Comment: I am using seet.seed(129) and getting: sum (sampleA > 0.3599999999999999866773 )/ M= 32000.00000000000000000  para N = 36.0000000000000000000 : 0.998125000000000039968. Isn't what you expect?

Comment: The ideal values ​​should be
P(Xbar> 0.36) = P (Z> -2.909845) = 1 - P (Z <-2.909845) = 0.998192
sum (samplea> 0.36) / M = 32000 for N = 36: 0.9984063, but your answer is very close, What did you do?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea which is seet.seed (129)

Comment: Also check Zn<- (X - n*miu)/(sigma*sqrt(n)), I think it should be (X - n*miu)/(sigma/sqrt(n))